# why the npm link did not work with typescript

Tags: typescript, npm

I want to use `npm link` to quickly modify the public component `rd-component`, in the `rd-component` folder , I execute this command :

```
npm link
```

and I check the link successfully linked to global:

```
> npm root -g
/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules
> cd /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules
> ls
@babel                     cnpm                       hexo-cli                   rc-component               typescript
@vue                       corepack                   npm                        rd-component               typescript-language-server
appdmg                     gulp                       nrm                        react-app-rewired          vite
> ls -alh
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  17 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   544B May  1 15:03 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   128B Jan 11  2022 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   128B Mar  3  2022 @babel
drwxr-xr-x   3 xiaoqiangjiang  staff    96B Jan 23  2022 @vue
drwxr-xr-x  12 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   384B Jul  7  2022 appdmg
drwxr-xr-x   9 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   288B Jul  7  2022 cnpm
drwxr-xr-x   7 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   224B Jan 11  2022 corepack
drwxr-xr-x   9 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   288B Apr  6 01:51 gulp
drwxr-xr-x  10 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   320B Mar 27  2022 hexo-cli
drwxr-xr-x  13 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   416B Jan 11  2022 npm
drwxr-xr-x  10 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   320B Mar 11 15:33 nrm
drwxr-xr-x  11 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   352B May  1 15:03 rc-component
lrwxr-xr-x   1 xiaoqiangjiang  staff    55B May  1 15:01 rd-component -> ../../../../../../source/reddwarf/frontend/rd-component
drwxr-xr-x  13 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   416B Mar 11 16:01 react-app-rewired
drwxr-xr-x@  9 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   288B Mar 21 01:00 typescript
drwxr-xr-x@  7 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   224B Mar 21 01:00 typescript-language-server
drwxr-xr-x  12 xiaoqiangjiang  staff   384B Jan 28  2022 vite
```

the next in the working folder, I using this command:

```
npm link rd-component
```

and checked the link:

```
> ls -alh ./node_modules|grep "rd-component"
lrwxr-xr-x    1 xiaoqiangjiang  staff    18B May  2 21:06 rd-component -> ../../rd-component
```

when I changed the public component, the working workspace could not recognize the change of public component `rd-component`. Am I missing something? what should I do to make it work so that I can direct change the public component and do not need to publish to public repository to apply the change.